# How can I generate random numbers inside my shortcodes on each implementation?

Tags: php, shortcode

I am making shortcodes with the random class like this

The random alphnumeric generator:

```
function getRandomCode(){
    $alphanumeric = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $su = strlen($alphanumeric) - 1;
    // echo '<br/>';
    // // echo rand(0, $su);
    // // echo '<br/>';
    // // echo substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 3);
    // // echo '<br/>';
    echo substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 3) .
            substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 2).
            substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 1).
            substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 1);
}


function heading( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // [my_heading][/my_heading]
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(), $atts, 'my_heading' );

    // do shortcode actions here
    $output = "<h1 class=\"my-theme-element-". getRandomCode() ." banner-heading test-class-1\">".$content."</h1>";
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_heading','heading' );
```

The random class is `my-theme-element-".getRandomCode()."`

`The Problem`:

The problem is it is not generating the class as expected means it is generating it above the page, not inside the h1 tag. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you echo instead of returning

Comment: As @MarkKaplun said your specific issue is that `getRandomCode` *echo* instead of *return*. Also I would suggest [`wp_generate_uuid4`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_uuid4/) to don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @Mark Kaplun comment:

Make your `getRandomCode()` return value instead of echo like this

```
function getRandomCode(){
    $alphanumeric = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $su = strlen($alphanumeric) - 1;
    // echo '<br/>';
    // // echo rand(0, $su);
    // // echo '<br/>';
    // // echo substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 3);
    // // echo '<br/>';
    return substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 3) .
            substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 2).
            substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 1).
            substr($alphanumeric, rand(0, $su), 1);
}
```

and remember do not make change to your shortcode callback